# How can i connect to LAN computers trough (SoftEther) VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, lan, softether

I have a SoftEther (v2.45) VPN server running on Arch Linux.

- The SoftEther hub is bridged to physical nic *ens33* on the server computer.
- When i connect the (Android) cellphone to my VPN, trough cellphone 3G service, I can connect to internet sites seemingly just fine trough my LAN gateway.

  - *Confirmed by going to e.g whatsmyip.com or whoer.net in cellphone browser and seeing my regular external ip instead of the cellphone provider's.*
- The cellphone gets assigned a LAN ip as well, in the range set on the DHCP at the local gateway.

However, when trying to connect to the any other computer on the lan using IP:PORT in browsers address field *(e.g 192.168.0.5:8080, where serving a web page which works fine from other computers on the lan)*, the cellphone simply can't access the page or goes to search engine set on it using the ip:port as a query.

So I'm wondering if someone might have some tips as what might be going on,  or how to go about troubleshooting it further? Seeing as the phone apparently can connect to the lan's gateway/DHCP, and the outside web trough that gateway. Yet for some reason not any of the other computers connected on the very same LAN , where all the other devices are using the same gateway/dhcp as the phone to access the internet..

- There are no firewalls active on the lan computers tested
- The computer where SoftEther is running, can connect to other computers on the lan just fine, and vice-versa

Comment: For some reason it seems possible to actually make connection to lan computers, but **very** sporadically. So it seems the problem might rather be with incredibly crappy 3G signal, the phone itself, or SoftEther; causing the connections to constantly drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was rather caused by very unstable 3G connection, and not SoftEther itself.